# Vector with references to same object

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I am learning myself C++. To understand how a Vector works, I wrote the somewhat strange code below:

Schuif is a user defined class, the value of ArSize is 10.

======================

```
Schuif schuif;
Schuif &TempSchuif = schuif;

for(size_t i=0; i<ArSize; ++i)
{
    cout << "vector size = " << SchuifVector.size() << endl;
    cout << "vector capacity = " << SchuifVector.capacity() << endl;

    SchuifVector.push_back(TempSchuif);
}
```

With this code I expect to end up with a vector of 10 elements where all elements contain a reference to the same schuif object.

However, when I compile this code, I have a vector with 10 different objects schuif.

This wonders me what is the push_back function of the vector container realy doing? It seams to be that it is not adding the reference to the vector but making a copy of schuif and put that reference in the vector.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not what happens. `push_back` will copy its argument into the vector, so you end up with a vector containing ten copies of `schuif`, not ten references to it.

You cannot create a vector of references in C++, but you can create a vector of pointers:

```
vector<Shuif *> v;
for (int i = 0; i < ArSize; i++) {
    v.push_back(&schuif);
}
```